# Allowing users from a non trusted domain to Dimension data

Tags: reporting-services, ssas

Domain A = SSRS Users
Domain B = SSRS and SSAS instances

There are around 5 separate roles to segregate the allowed member set in dimension data. Domain A user(s) cannot be added to SSAS Cube role(s) in Domain B since Domain A is not trusted to Domain B. What is the best way to enable SSAS Dimensional data level security for User(s) from Domain A?

TIA!

Comment: How will users in Domain A sign into SSRS? Do Domain A users also have Domain B accounts? Is SSRS the only client tool for Domain A users to access SSAS or do you intend to provide Excel PivotTable access too?

Comment: There is a public IP/URL set for SSRS. There are Excel Pivot Report templates which is connecting the cube dbs(either with http access through SSAS data pump or through regular port 2383) are created and is planned to be hosted in SSRS Folders so that Domain A users can access it using their Domain A account. There are no Domain B accounts for the users from Domain A.

Comment: The SSRS server is in Domain B and Domain A users can already log into SSRS using their Domain A username? If that works why can't Domain A users be added to SSAS roles? Are you sure Domain B doesn't trust Domain A?

Comment: SSAS instance is in separate intranet. I was leaning towards creating Local Users in SSAS servers who is added Dimensional data level security and write an Excel VB script to find the Domain A user who is accessing the Report template and keep the mapping of Domain A users to SSAS Servers Local Users somwhere in a SQL DB table and use the specific local user authentication in the Excel. Is there a better idea to implement it?

Comment: Can you tell me exactly how users log into SSRS which is in Domain B?

Comment: I am sorry that I am not explaining it very well. Hope this clarifies. SSRS Instance=Intranet1, SSAS Instance=Intranet2. DomainA\Users(SSRS Report Users) can be granted permission till SSRS Folders in SSRS Instance but cannot be added to Intranet2.  DomainB\Users has access to all environments(both SSRS, SSAS)

Comment: So SSRS server is joined to Domain A? And Domain A trusts Domain B but not vice versa?

Comment: Yes & yes. SSRS is joined to Domain A. I need to filter data to Domain A users from Cube dimension which is in Domain B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward solution would be to move the SSAS server to Domain A. That's where the users are. Plus, if it's in Domain A, then Domain B users can connect since Domain A trusts Domain B one way. I would highly recommend this.

If that's not an option, then you might try this. In SSRS, you should be able to set the credentials on the SSAS data source to use DOMAINB\ServiceAccount. Then it should be able to pull SSAS data into SSRS.

To bake role based security into SSAS, I see two options. First, you might just create 5 reports and use SSRS security to control who can see which report. Behind the scenes, each of the 5 identical reports would use a different service account on the SSRS data source to connect to SSAS. Basically each use would be granted access to one of the 5 reports and that report would connect using one of the 5 service accounts to SSAS and role based security in SSAS would show the appropriate data for that one service account.

If that's not acceptable you might consider using dynamic security using CustomData since you can't have Domain A users connecting to SSAS on Domain B.

Typical dynamic security uses one role with an MDX expression and the UserName() MDX function to lookup what the current user can access:
http://hccmsbi.blogspot.com/2007/08/implementing-user-specific-security-in.html

Your situation since you can't actually connect to SSAS on Domain B with Domain A users, you could use the CustomData() MDX function instead of the UserName() MDX function. You may have to use an expression based connection string in SSRS. The hardcoded connection string would look like:
Data Source=ssasserver.domainb.local;Initial Catalog=YourDB;CustomData=JoeBlow

The one role would only have to have DOMAINB\ServiceAccount as a member. But internally it would use the CustomData connection string property to figure out "who you are" and what dimension members you can see.

As far as Excel, I'm thinking you could setup 5 msmdpump virtual directories and then in IIS grant each Domain A user access to only one. However, I'm not clear on how that would work because I don't know how you would setup IIS to impersonate a Domain B service account when it connects to SSAS. Had you already thought through this?

Let me know if that doesn't make sense. Again, I would recommend moving SSAS to Domain A.

Comment: Thank you Greg for the inputs.

Comment: Hi @harharsar if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.